# Como puede separar un String en java sin utilizar un delimitador

Tags: java, string, split

A partir de un String *2654993672*, lo que deseo es separarlo en dos partes.

```
String part1 = "26";
String part2 = "54993672";
```

Con el método split() puedo separarlos con un delimitador...

```
String[] parts = string.split("-");
String part1 = parts[0]; 
String part2 = parts[1];
```

Pero lo que necesito es separarlos sin utilizarlo.

Comment: si necesitas separar siempre los dos primeros dígitos, podrías probar con `substring`

Comment: bajo que logica hay que separar los numeros??? porque de eso depende tu algoritmo..

Comment: El ejercicio es para desarrollar un sistema de retail o tienda. El usuario ingresa primeramente la cantidad a despachar, por ejemplo = "+3" y luego, introduce el codigo de barra. De este modo, ese articulo se introduce en una tabla con la cantidad '3' (El sistema toma en cuenta la posicion 0 y 1 del texto). También podria introducir '+10', y en ese caso debe tomarse en cuenta el codigo de barra  a partir de la posicion 2 del texto. Depende de la cantidad ingresada tras un signo '+'

Comment: El problema es que por ejemplo si se ingresa 30, la lógica debería reconocer que son 30 y no 3... como mencionas estas desarrollando ese sistema de retail, no cabría la posibilidad de diferenciar de alguna forma mediante un signo? o un espacio? Completamente seguro?

Comment: Tal vez si introdujera un "3+" en vez de "+3"?...

Comment: Tengo una duda, el signo **+** se guarda también al momento de introducirlo? Porque si se guardase, podrías aplicar un `split` sin problema

Comment: Asi es... Al poner el signo '+' por delante del número, el split pasa a ser lo único que necesito. Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Para dividir el string sin usar delimitador podes usar 'substring'
Tiene un sensillo uso:

```
var str = "Hello world!";
var res = str.substring(1, 4); -> res == "ell"
```

Entendiendo como son los arreglos que siempre empiezan por la posicion 0, deberias pensar que **str** al momento de dividirse es un arreglo de chars y substring(POSINICIAL, POSFINAL) lleva dos posiciones del arreglo.

Primero POSINICIAL es la posicion N>=0 donde quieres que comienze tu string, y POSFINAL la ultima posicion **NO INCLUSIVE**

Para ver mejor el ejemplo, ingresa a este [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp)